# How to select all enum values with a stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called 'products' where I have stored the Category as enum. My issue is that when I try to fetch all values in this column using a prepared statement in PHP I can not figure out how to do it. I have managed to fetch specific values both by numeric value and by string with prepared statements, and I have managed to select all values with SQL-queries in MySQL.

SQL stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `SearchProduct`(IN `xKeyword` VARCHAR(255), IN `xPriceMin` DECIMAL(10,2), 
IN `xPriceMax` DECIMAL(10,2), IN `xCategory` ENUM('Kläder','Musik','Poster','Instrument'))
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM products
WHERE Name LIKE xKeyword
AND Price BETWEEN xPriceMin AND xPriceMax
AND Description LIKE xKeyword
AND Category IN xCategory;
END
```

PHP code:

```
//Default values
$Keyword = "%";
$PriceMin = 0;
$PriceMax = 99999999.99;
$FilterCategory = "(1, 2, 3, 4)";

//Connect to database
$Conn = Connect();

//Prepare and execute SQL
$SQL = $Conn->prepare("CALL SearchProduct (?, ?, ?, ?)");
$SQL->bind_param("sdds", $Keyword, $PriceMin, $PriceMax, $FilterCategory);
$SQL->execute();
$SQL->bind_result($ProductID, $Name, $Price, $Description, $Category);
    
//Show results
while ($SQL->fetch()) {
    echo '<div class="product"><h3>' . $Name . '</h3><p>' . $Price . '</p><p>' . $Description . '</p><p>' . $Category . '</p></div>';
}

//Close all connections
$SQL->close();
$Conn->close();
```

I have tried setting $FilterCategory to all kinds of values, and as long as it matches just a single value everything works.
But I want the possiblity to show all products even if no filter is applied to Category.

My last resort would be to create another table just for categories and then link them in as Foreign keys, but I would prefer to avoid that.

Comment: MySQL says: `To determine all possible values for an ENUM column, use SHOW COLUMNS FROM tbl_name LIKE 'enum_col' and parse the ENUM definition in the Type column of the output. ` That was found near the end of [this section](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/enum.html#enum-literals) ... I personally do not care for ENUMs, this being one of the reasons. I'd rather have a simple lookup table. Another reason is that any ENUM change requires an `ALTER TABLE` to change. With a lookup, all I need is a simple insert, delete, or set an active column (if present) to 0/1 to disable/enable entries.

Answer (score 0):

For a table you may get all ENUM values by inserting their numeric indices. SQL statement which inserts fake row and table/columns names may be hardcoded, or dynamic SQL may be used.

Small example:

> ```
> CREATE TABLE test (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
>                    val ENUM('value 1', 'value 2'));
> ```

> ```
> CREATE PROCEDURE gather_enum_list ( OUT valueslist TEXT )
> BEGIN
> DECLARE done TINYINT DEFAULT 0;
> DECLARE enumindex TINYINT DEFAULT 0;
> DECLARE fakeid INT;
> DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR 1265
>     BEGIN
>         SET done := 1;
>     END;
> INSERT INTO test (val) VALUES (NULL);
> SET fakeid = LAST_INSERT_ID();
> cycle: LOOP
>     SET enumindex = enumindex + 1;
>     UPDATE test SET val = enumindex WHERE id = fakeid;
>     IF done THEN 
>         LEAVE cycle;
>     END IF;
>     SET valueslist = CONCAT_WS(',', valueslist, (SELECT val FROM test WHERE id = fakeid));
> END LOOP;
> DELETE FROM test WHERE id = fakeid;
> END
> ```

> ```
> CALL gather_enum_list(@output);
> SELECT @output as ENUM_values_list;
> ```
>
> ```
> | ENUM_values_list |
> | :--------------- |
> | value 1,value 2  |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f0cdd48cdedbf60d9a85f1652f0b6f5d)*

For compound statement parameter - parse its code text, this is the only option.